# How to resize an HDF5 array with `h5py`

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

How can I resize an HDF5 array using the `h5py` Python library ?

I've tried using the `.resize` method and on an array with `chunks` set to `True`.  Alas, I'm still missing something.

```
In [1]: import h5py

In [2]: f = h5py.File('foo.hdf5', 'w')

In [3]: d = f.create_dataset('data', (3, 3), dtype='i8', chunks=True)

In [4]: d.resize((6, 3))
/home/mrocklin/Software/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/_hl/dataset.pyc in resize(self, size, axis)
--> 277         self.id.set_extent(size)
ValueError: unable to set extend dataset (Dataset: Unable to initialize object)

In [11]: h5py.__version__ 
Out[11]: '2.2.1'
```

Comment: Perhaps it is something to do with the datatype of the array... Maybe try a more standard datatype such as one shown in the documentation for initializing an array?

Comment: Just tried it with no dtype specified (I think it defaults to float).  Same error

Comment: Are you missing `maxshape` on `create_dataset`?

Comment: @SlightlyCuban that solves it.  Does `maxshape` allocate that much space on disk?  Why not set it infinite?

Comment: @MRocklin what version of h5py are you using? I just tried this using 2.2.1 and didn't have a problem.

Comment: @SlightlyCuban added in edit.  2.2.1

Comment: @MRocklin not sure why it isn't working on your end. That code should do the same as `create_dataset('data', (3, 3), dtype='i8', chunks=True, maxshape=(None, None))`. For the record, I'm on libhdf5 1.8.5

Answer (score 16):

As mentioned by Oren, you need to use `maxshape` when creating the `dataset` if you want to change the array size later. Setting a dimension to `None` allows you to resize that dimension up to 2**64 (h5's limit) later:

```
In [1]: import h5py

In [2]: f = h5py.File('foo.hdf5', 'w')

In [3]: d = f.create_dataset('data', (3, 3), maxshape=(None, 3), dtype='i8', chunks=True)

In [4]: d.resize((6, 3))

In [5]: h5py.__version__
Out[5]: '2.2.1'
```

See the [docs](http://docs.h5py.org/en/2.3/high/dataset.html#resizable-datasets) for more.

Answer (score 4):

You need to change this line:

```
d = f.create_dataset('data', (3, 3), dtype='i8', chunks=True)
```

To

```
d = f.create_dataset('data', (3, 3), maxshape=(?, ?), dtype='i8', chunks=True) 

d.resize((?, ?))
```

Change the **?** to whatever size you what (You can also set it to **None**)

Read here:
http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html#resizable-datasets